# Obtener HTML de instagram

Tags: php, dom

Tengo este código, pero el file_get_contents no funciona correctamente.

```
  $html = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/');


    $dom = new domDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $img_id =  $image->getAttribute('id');

        if($img_id == 'hi_2') {
            echo $image->getAttribute('src');

        }
    }
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Realiza peticiones cURL.

Comment: y cómo se hace eso? lo siento pero soy nuevo en todo esto

Comment: Procura explicar todo mejor. Qué intentas? Cual es el resultado esperado? Por que no funciona correctamente?

Comment: Quiero obtener el HTML de Instagram para cojer el src de una img en concreto, es decir, el resultado final de este código debería devolver una cadena de texto con el src especifico. Creo el el "file_get_contents" obtiene algo de html pero no todo.

Comment: @PauG.P. tienes la opción de [editar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/51522/edit) debido a que no está clara tu pregunta. Asimismo, puedes visitar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _$channel = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($channel,CURLOPT_URL,$this->url);
        curl_setopt($channel,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($channel,CURLOPT_GET,true);
        $response = curl_exec($channel);
        curl_close($channel);
        print_r($response);_
Ya tienes el html , la gente de vez de poner que no es clara la pregunta primero tienen que saber sobre que no es clara o informase un poco , se pueden hacer peticiones cURL , si no hay conocimiento no tiene que bloquearse una pregunta por eso mismo por desconocer la respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias! Lamentablemente creo que instagram usa js para mostrar la información y no soy capaz de obtenerla del html

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Pau G.P.

Si imprimes tu variable $html verás que no existe ninguna etiqueta de imagen en el cuerpo del html devuelto. El código funciona correctamente, seguramente todo el contenido se carga mediante ajax con javascript.

file_get_contents('url') solo obtiene el código inicial y no ejecuta javascript.

Comment: Tiene sentido, ¿hay alguna forma de obtener el código entonces?

Comment: @PauG.P.  Con PHP creo que no , ya que no hay manera de obtener y ejecutar el código Javascript desde php.  Debes buscar otra alternativa. Si te interesa obtener las imagenes de instagram , ¿has pensado en que pueden tener una API , para ello ? , puede que en la página de instagram para desarrolladores halla algo util para ti https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593155/how-to-get-pictures-url-from-instagram-api-json-result